How can I Import GCP's OAuth 2.0 client to terraform
I want to import terraform of GCP's OAuth 2.0 client. However, I don't know terraform's resource name of OAuth client.
It's not client for IAP.
I want to create client of normal client ID of desktop.
If you know how to create the client, please share.
I searched information from terraform document and GCP document.
terraform GCP docs
GCP docs

Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read this first: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Closed due to the following reasons

Resource is not provided by Terraform
It is difficult to convert gcloud commands using scripts because Google Cloud does not provide APIs.

